# flipping the axes of a barchart

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, charts

It is not common of me to work with Barcharts but as I'm currently working on a project that requires the use of Barcharts I find flipping the axes to be extremely tedious and quite honestly, frustrating given most of the command are more 'aesthetic' leaning.

Here are my codes:

> BarChart3D[{0.36, 0.15, 0.07, 0.09, 0.23, 0.08, 0.15}, 
>    ChartLabels -> {"Any disability", "Hearing difficulty", 
>      "Vision difficulty", "Cognitive difficulty", 
>      "Ambulatory difficulty", "Self-care difficulty", 
>      "Independent living difficulty"}]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add the option `BarOrigin -> Left` ?

Comment: Is that all there is to solving the issues?

Comment: Apparently, it is. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  I am going to mark this as "easily found in the documentation" as it is there under **Options**, but at the same time I know it really helps to know in advance what you are looking for.